# Using Case to Return Different Sets of Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, case

I'm trying to create a T-SQL query that returns two separate queries (or if there is a much better way of writing this I would really like to know without using `CASE` that's fine too! I'm interested to know!)

A simplified quasi-code version of the query

```
DECLARE @ALob VARCHAR = 'Item1' /*Or User can write in 'All'*/

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @ALob='Item1' THEN 
        (Select e.EventID, e.EventName, Count(*) Rows
        From tbl_Events e
        Where BLob='Item1') 
    WHEN @ALob='All'THEN
        (Select e.EventID, e.EventName, Count(*) Rows
        From tbl_Events e) END
```

So pretty much a user can write in the `DECLARE` section 'ALL' or 'Item1' And depending on what they put in it'll either display the first query or the second query.

Now it's important to note that the second query has no `Where BLob='Item1'` which is important, because the Lob in the 'All' selection can be ANYTHING - NULL, Item1, whatever - and I want to pull up everything.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use CASE/WHEN to control the flow of execution.  Instead, you need to use IF/THEN, like this:

```
DECLARE @ALob VARCHAR = 'Item1' /*Or User can write in 'All'*/

IF @ALob='Item1'
  Begin
        Select e.EventID, e.EventName, Count(*) Rows
        From tbl_Events e
        Where BLob='Item1'
  End
Else If @ALob='All'
  Begin
        Select e.EventID, e.EventName, Count(*) Rows
        From tbl_Events e
  End
Else
  Begin
    Select 'Unrecognized selection'
  End
```

Comment: Huh - honestly did not know I could even use IF/THEN statements - I'll try it out!

Comment: Hmm - It looks like it ran successfully but it doesn't spit out any actual information - it just reads 'Command(s) completed successfully'

Comment: If your not getting results, it's probably because @ALob is not matching Item1 or All.  Please check my edits.  This shows how to use a default condition for the If/Then